# Android Java automatically login to website

Tags: java, android

This is my first android app.
My background is in C#.
I'm stuck trying to automate the submission of the web form on this site:
https://ppcplus.121fcu.org/Mobile/Features/Auth/MFA/MFALogin.aspx

I'm able to load the page and view the html in a TextView but not submit the form.
Ultimately this project is intended to be a completely hands-off, 0-steps, home-screen widget that will show me my total balance from bank accounts, paypal, etc. I've searched and searched trying all sorts of different variations with no luck. In firefox I can get the textbox filled out but still can't get the form to actually submit. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public static void connectToSite(){

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();


    try{            
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://ppcplus.121fcu.org/Mobile/Features/Auth/MFA/MFALogin.aspx");
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("UserIDValue", "12345"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        responseString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is/isn't happening?

Comment: If the post worked, it would show me the html of the next page instead the original page

Comment: log 'response' and find out what the server is responding with. that will help you find and address the issue

Comment: how do I do that? (I'm using eclipse with the android package) I don't think it's responding with anything because the form never gets submitted... responseString gets displayed in a TextView. That's what I'm currently using to check on the result.